# Is there any way to implement Zod in javascript (Next 14 & React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, zod

In a some case i need to implement Zod with javascript not typescript, i've already tried so many ways to reach that, but got nothing, the first one i did execute `create-next-app@latest` with no `--typescript` flag, after that i'd install `zod` and import it to some `page.jsx` or some component, but it doesn't works at all like image below:

[image: import z from JS]

at this image, i'm trying to import `z` from zod, but i got nothing it's just a namespace / constructor class types

but when i implement it on the typescript, here's what i got:

[image: import z from TS]

in this case, i've already tried so many ways to find the solution

### 1. define it with JSDoc

i was defining the `z` type with JSDoc, but it still doesn't work such as this image below:
[image: define z with JSDoc]

### 2. trying to configure with jsconfig

here's what i'd configure to my `jsconfig.js`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@lib/*": ["./src/lib/*"]
    },
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "target": "es5",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "incremental": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "ESNext"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "next-env.d.ts", "**/*.js", "**/*.jsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

3. Already tried with JSDoc it worked but weird.
   as you can see at first image below that `zod` is not typed well, but the second image, it worked but still not typed properly, like it's actually works, but it's not
4. [image: zod type]
5. [image: zod has types]

here's my versions at this project:

- Next -> 14.1.10
- Zod -> ^3.22.4